# How can I copy a text in Spanish, and avoid removing every single accent in the whole text?

Tags: accents, font-encodings, copy-paste

That's my problem folks. I have to do a language work, and I can't copy text, without removing every accents.

Comment: Welcome to SX. Could you please give more detail about your problem? Copy from where to where?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 6):

I assumed that your problem appears when running pdflatex on a document containing special characters from Spanish and copying from the resulting PDF file to another file.

In this case, to prevent the problem, simply use the Cork encoding: add in the preamble

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

If you don't do this, then special characters (accented vowels, the tilde in the "ñ" and the crema, in Spanish) won't be copyable from the obtained PDF document.